# Pause the code at some point

Tags: python, timer, wxpython

I want to pause the code at exact position and wait for the different input plus the start button clicked. However, if it is not achievable, how can I add another button into the start button to make it work?

```
import wx

import time

import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

global Total_Length
Total_Length = 500

global Input_Length
Input_Length = 0

a = 0


class tyler(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self,parent,id):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self,parent,id,'Lyquid Crystal Laser Control',size=(500,200))
        panel=wx.Panel(self)

        #global Text_1
        self.Text_1 = wx.TextCtrl(panel,-1,"0",(350,30),(50,30))
        self.Text_1.Bind(wx.EVT_TEXT_ENTER,self.Start)
        self.Text_1.Bind(wx.EVT_KILL_FOCUS,self.Start)


        self.timer = wx.Timer(self)
        #self.Bind(wx.EVT_TIMER, self.timer)
        button_1=wx.Button(panel,label="Start",pos=(400,80),size=(80,30))
        button_2=wx.Button(panel,label="Stop",pos=(400,120),size=(80,30))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.Start, button_1)
        #self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.Stop, button_2)

    def Start(self,event):
        global a
        Input_Length=float(self.Text_1.GetValue())
        #print(Input_Length)
        #a = Input_Length
        #print(Input_Length)
        dc=float(100*Input_Length/Total_Length)
        GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
        GPIO.setup(18,GPIO.OUT)
        GPIO.setwarnings(False)
        p = GPIO.PWM(18,1150)
        p.start(0)
        p.ChangeDutyCycle(dc)
        p.ChangeFrequency(1150)
            #I wanted to pause the code at here, until the input changes, and the start button clicked, so I add timer in below, however, the output is only a pulse but the square wave is what I wanted 
        if a == dc:
            self.timer.Start(1000)
        else:
            a = dc
            self.timer.Stop()
            #def Stop(self,event):
            GPIO.cleanup()



if __name__=='__main__':
    app=wx.PySimpleApp()
    frame=tyler(parent=None,id=-1)
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 0):

"Pause and wait" and "event-driven GUI programming" do not go together. As long as the main GUI thread is blocked waiting for something, then other events can't be processed and the program will appear to be frozen.  Your options are to change how you "wait" (by not actually waiting) or to use another thread.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38331131/read-parameters-like-eta-from-youtube-dl/38342330#38342330) to another question applies just as well here, and will give you more information and pointers.